# How do I check whether or not a typed property has a value in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue in vanilla JS and have a property defined in my data of type string which looks like this

```js
data() {
  return {
    DimensionSetting: { type : String }
  }
}
```

I have an element in my template that I want to toggle off when a value is passed into `DimensionSetting` however I can't figure out how I need to check for it in the `v-if` logic.  I tried `v-if="!this.DimensionSetting"` and `v-if="this.DimensionSetting === undefined"` and `v-if="this.DimensionSetting === null"`.  None of these make the element visible when the value is empty.  What do I need to do to properly check that kind of property?

Comment: You don't need to use `this` when you access variables from within the template. Just use `if(DimensionSetting)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're incorrectly mixing a [`data` property](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#data-2) declaration with a [`props`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#props) declaration.

If `DimensionSetting` is supposed to be a public property that receives values from a parent component, it should be declared under `props`:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    DimensionSetting: {
      type: String,
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if `DimensionSetting` is supposed to be a local property, private to the component itself, then it should be returned from `data()`. There is no `type` field like there is for `props` declarations:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      DimensionSetting: ''
    }
  }
}
```

In either case, using the `!` operator on the prop should be enough to check for an empty string:

```html
<p v-if="!DimensionSetting">Empty</p>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-prop-declaration?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

try adding,

```
data(){
  return{
          DimensionSetting: { type : String ,default:false}
        }
}
```

and then `v-if="!DimensionSetting"`

Comment: I think it's more of `prop` issue